# Drools: How rules can be extended in decision tables

Tags: drools

I know in .drl files, rules can be inherited using the `extends` keyword. But how this can be achieved in decision tables?

Comment: What do you mean by extension in decision tables? Like for example adding new columns to spreadsheet?

Comment: implementing a rule like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342054/drools-rules-inheritance using decision tables

Comment: you can't do that. You may try to build rule at runtime though and extend it dynamically.