# Can we reuse a rule in drools?

Tags: drools, reusability

I have couple of individual rules. Now for example, I have 3 different set of rules to be executed. Based on the input parameters, at any point a set of rules are to be executed. Let's say in the first set/group there are 5 rules, in the second set/group there are 7 rules and in the third set/group there are 5 rules. Now all these sets might have common rule(s) and I want to refer them instead of having the rule written 3 times in each of the set. How can this be achieved in drools? Tomorrow if I have make an update, I should be able to make the change to the rule only once and this change should reflect in all the sets. Kindly advice on this.....

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342054/drools-rules-inheritance) to reuse rule logic and you can write reusable DSL statements and write your logic in rdslr.
Another good [inheritance example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084833/single-inheritance-in-drools/61129674#61129674) with explanations

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately inheritance doesn't solve my purpose. All my rules are individual and not dependent of each other. A rule can be part of two or more rulesets/groups and all the rules in that set/group should execute. I have as many as 1000+ rules and around 500 rulesets/groups which reuse the individual rules.

Comment: when you say 'reuse' doesn't it mean 'rules have something in common'? so you can 'reuse common parts' using inheritance. don't understand you arguments

Comment: Let me explain.... For example, I have rule A, rule B, rule C, rule D and rule E. Now the first group has rule A, B, C and second group has B, C, D, E and third group has rule A, D, E and fourth group has rule B, C, D, E. Like this there can be N number of rules and N number of groups. Please note that rule A, B, C, D and E are independent of each other and there is absolutely no dependency or anything in common. It is just that the groups will have a set of rules. Now based on the input parameters either first group or second group or third group or fourth group might get executed.

Comment: Also if I change rule A then the changes should reflect in all the groups that rule A is part of and I should not go to each group to change the logic as rules are independent and the groups should reference the original rules.

Comment: that's exactly what you can achieve with inheritance and DSL reuse

Comment: Can you please provide me an example? Again I don't see any attribute as "extend". https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.37.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#rules-attributes-ref_drl-rules

Comment: did you look at link I've provided in the answer?

Comment: Yeah I did take a look but I am still confused. My rules are individual and independent. When I say Rule B extends Rule A, do I need to write the logic for Rule B again when I already have a individual .drl created for Rule B?  Please bear with me as I am very new to drools. If I have to use Rule B in another ruleset/group and if it doesn't have Rule A then how should I go about it?

Comment: If I create a new rule package, package one then how can I call the individual rules like 


package One

import rule "A"
import rule "B"
import rule "D"


and when I create a new rule package, package two


package Two

import rule "A"
import rule "B"
import rule "C"


then when I create a new rule package, package three

package Three

import rule "C"
import rule "D"
import rule "E"


How do I reference the individual rules A, B, C, D, E in these packages?

Comment: make a test for yourself and try. I'm not sure what rule packages are you talking about and imports.

Comment: I think possibly they want rule flows/agenda groups rather than inheritence, with rules shared between different flows/groups.